# How should I improve my javascript form validation?

Tags: javascript, forms

I grabbed the form from some random site because I'm only interested writing the javascript at the moment.

I am trying to check that a user has selected or entered text for all fields. I've made it a long if if-else but that can't be the best/most elegant/easiest solution.

Leaving aside the radio button validation for now, what's the better way to check that the text fields, drop down, and checkboxes all have a value/input?

I'm teaching myself javascript so I'm open to being told the proper way and I'll research it and do it on my own, or updating my fiddle would be fine too. (Be gentle with me. I'm sure this code is janky.)

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kiddigit/g0rur21a/

```
document.getElementById("newForm").addEventListener("submit", enterForm);

function enterForm(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var dropdown = document.getElementById('dropDown');

    if (document.getElementById('fname').value === ''){ 
            document.getElementById('fname').focus(); 
            alert('Enter text.');
        } else if (document.getElementById('eMail').value === ''){
            document.getElementById('eMail').focus();
            alert('Enter text.');
            } else if  (document.getElementById('textArea').value === '') {
                document.getElementById('textArea').focus();
                alert('Enter text.');
                } else if (!dropDown.value) {
                    document.getElementById('dropDown').focus();
                    alert('Choose an option.');
                    } else if ( ( newForm.checkbox[0].checked == false ) && ( newForm.checkbox[1].checked == false ) ) 
                        { alert ( "Please choose a checkbox" ); 
                            return false;
                            }

    var radios = document.getElementsByName("radio");
    var formValid = false;
    var i = 0;
    while (!formValid && i < radios.length) {
        if (radios[i].checked) formValid = true;
            i++;        
        }

        if (!formValid) alert("Please check a radio button.");
        return formValid;

        return false;
};
```

Comment: If this code currently works as designed and you're just looking for feedback on it, this would likely be more appropriate on the Code Review SE site.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know about that site. I'll post there.

Answer (score 1):

If you use HTML5, and assuming you're NOT using jQuery for anything (just native JavaScript), a good convention would be to assign a class to all input elements in the form that you want to validate (or if they all need to be validated, you can get all child elements of the form), and use getElementsByClassName(). With HTML5 data-* attributes, you can assign something like data-invalid-error-message to set the error message for the element itself.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp

From there, you can perform a loop across all elements, check if they're empty, and then grab the data-invalid-error-message attribute and display it to the user without doing nested if statements.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("newForm").addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  if (!document.getElementById('fname').value) {
    return alert('Enter text.');
  }

  if (document.getElementById('eMail').value === '') {
    document.getElementById('eMail').focus();
    return alert('Enter text.');
  }

  if (document.getElementById('textArea').value === '') {
    document.getElementById('textArea').focus();
    return alert('Enter text.');
  }

  var dropdown = document.getElementById('dropDown');
  if (!dropdown || !dropDown.value) {
    document.getElementById('dropDown').focus();
    return alert('Choose an option.');
  }

  if (( newForm.checkbox[0].checked == false ) && ( newForm.checkbox[1].checked == false )) {
    return alert("Please choose a checkbox");
  }

  var radios = document.getElementsByName("radio");
  var formValid = false;
  var i = 0;
  while (!formValid && i < radios.length) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
      formValid = true;
    }
    i++;
  }

  if (!formValid) {
    return alert("Please check a radio button.");
  }

  // Form is valid here
});
```

Here is some improvements. [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g0rur21a/1/)

I would like to validate form with `required` property, but it does not support validation of group of options and radio groups

Comment: Very nice. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK not supporting IE8, you can use `querySelectorAll` to dynamically get all the nodes of different types within your form and validate them accordingly. This will work for a form with any number of inputs:

```
function validateForm(formNode) {
    var formValid = true;
    var textFlds = formNode.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"],input[type="email"],input[type="password"],textarea');
    var dropdowns = formNode.querySelectorAll('select');
    var checks = formNode.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
    var anyChecked = false;
    var radios = formNode.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
    var anyRadios = false;
    for (var i = 0, l = textFlds.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (!textFlds[i].value) {
            textFlds[i].focus();
            alert('Please enter text into the ' + textFlds[i].name + ' field.');
            formValid = false
            break;
        }
    };

    for (var i = 0, l = dropdowns.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (formValid && !dropdowns[i].value) {
            dropdowns[i].focus();
            alert('Please choose an option from the ' + dropdowns[i].name + ' selector.');
            formValid = false
            break;
        }
    };

    for (var i = 0, l = checks.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (checks[i].checked) {
            anyChecked = true;
            break;
        }
    };
    if (formValid && !anyChecked) {
        alert('Please choose at least one of the checkboxes.');
        formValid = false;
    }

    for (var i = 0, l = radios.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {
            anyRadios = true;
            break;
        }
    };
    if (formValid && !anyRadios) {
        alert('Please check a radio button.');
        formValid = false;
    }

    return formValid;
}

document.getElementById('newForm').addEventListener('submit', function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();

        validateForm(this);
    });
```

This could be prettied up a bit, but you get the idea. ([fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/h52d055u/1/))

Comment: Cool. I thought about doing it this way but couldn't quite get it.